# What do status effects do against Behemoths?

Tags: dauntless

I see that there are a varying amount of status effects Behemoths can inflict on Slayers, but what about the status effects Slayers inflict on Behemoths? The wiki page makes no mention of the actual status effect application on them.  Specifically, what do the Fire, Ice, Shock, and Terra statuses do to behemoths, and do Radiant/Umbral weapons inflict any status elements at all?

Comment: Unless it's changed in the past few months, they don't inflict any status. Those are just damage types and are strong/weak against each other.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill They are extremely visible though -- after dealing a set amount of blaze damage behemoths are lit on fire, after enough frost damage, a chilling effect shows up.  Lightning only seems to stun them temporarily, and the appropriate visual effects show up as well. With Terra, they glow green and start producing healing orbs, although the heal amount and orb amount is unknown to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the more advanced ones like Radiant weapons deal status effects but here's what I could find for the basic 4 elements.

Blaze = 2000 x Power Modifier damage over several seconds, split across all parts on the behemoth

Shock = about 5s stun

Frost = about 30s slow

Terra = damage dealt to the behemoth spawns healing orbs